# What does the minimum mean in the notation $0 < \epsilon < \text{min}\{-a_i, b_i : i = 1, \dots, n\}$?

Tags: notation

I am reading the basic properties of [Concave Minimization from Global Optimization: Deterministic Approaches](https://books.google.com.tr/books/about/Global_Optimization.html?id=usFjGFvuBDEC&redir_esc=y) by Horst and Tuy and I came across such a notation on p. 10:

$$0 < \epsilon < \text{min}\{-a_i, b_i : i = 1, \dots, n\}$$

I am having a hard time interpreting the RHS of the inequality above.  If $\epsilon$ was a vector, I would speculate that this notation would roughly mean: "choose the minimum of $-a_i$ and $b_i$ for $i$th element of the $\epsilon$. But I believe $\epsilon$ is a scalar here. So, what does this "minimum" notation really convey?

Comment: I guess it means the minimum of the $2n$ numbers $-a_1,-a_2,...,-a_n,b_1,b_2,...,b_n$